# Proof that $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I've tried by definition:

$\forall \text{ }\varepsilon>0 \text{ }\exists\text{ } \delta>0 \text{ such that, if } 0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta \text{ then } \left|\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|<\varepsilon$
but nothing comes from that. How could I prove that??

Comment: A hint is to use the fact that $x^2 \leq x^2 + y^2$ in the numerator.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, my mistake. I've miscounted the powers

Answer (score 5):

Choose $\delta=\epsilon$, then for arbitrary $0<\left|\left(x,y\right)\right|<\delta$,
$$ \left|\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-0\right|=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leqslant\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\epsilon $$

Comment: +1 , to show that the limit is 0 "in case the limit Exists" , because taking $δ=ϵ$ is almost same as taking $x=y$ which will then give $x^2/\sqrt{x^2+x^2}=x/\sqrt{2}=0$ along the line $x=y$ whereas the other Answer is more complete because it shows that which-ever "way" we go to (0,0) , the limit is same !

Answer (score 4):

you can try polar coordinates: $x=r\cos\varphi, y=r\sin\varphi$. Then you should calculate your limit for any $\varphi \in [0, 2\pi)$ when $r \to 0$.

$$\lim_{r\to0}\frac{r^2\cos^2\varphi}{r} = \lim_{r\to0}r\cos^2\varphi = 0$$

Since the value of limit does not depend on angle $\varphi$ it is equal to $0$.

Comment: +1 , this is more complete because it shows that which-ever "way" we go to (0,0) , the limit is same !

Comment: Why that works? Seems a little weird.